# VDR - Trouble writing to destination volume, error -1020 (sharing violation)

Tags: backup-restoration, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vdr

Using VMware Data Recovery 1.1, backing up to CIFS share and getting this error

1/18/2010 8:55:31 AM: Performing incremental back up of disk "Lun VM/VM-DB1-flat.vmdk" using "SCSI Hot-Add"
1/18/2010 8:55:32 AM: Trouble writing to destination volume, error -1020 ( sharing violation)

Integrity checks of the destination complete successfully and I tried rebooting the VDR appliance just in case.

To resolve the issue I removed the share from the VDR, pointed the backups to other destinations and renamed the VMware Data Recovery subfolder in the destination, then re-added the share and pointed the backups, this of course creates a new Backup Store.

Anyone have any ideas why this error is occuring, means I can't backup into this Backup Store any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do VDR with CIFS but it sounds like you've got some form of locking going on - can you create a new share and try that?